# converting an unknown long\int\short to double in C#

Tags: c#, double, type-conversion

In my app I have a scenario in which I get a list of unknown type that could be either int\long\short.

I need to convert this list to double.

what is the quickest and most efficient way to achieve this? (it needs to be as fast as it could be)

Comment: `List<unknwon type>` means `List<object>`? Why don't you use a generic method where the type `T` indicates the type?

Comment: How are you getting the list? Where does the data come from?

Comment: dynamic is best way for pushing type cast to runtime

Comment: @Arun, no, it's really not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have `List<object>` and you need to convert it to `List<double>`

Try this, this will work for all types which implements `IConvertible`. `long`, `int`, `short`, `float`,etc...

```
var doubleList = objectList.Select(x=> Convert.ToDouble(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
List<double> doubleList = intList.ConvertAll(x => (double)x);
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel read the question it is asked only for `int\long\short` not `object`

Comment: You read the question again! **In my app I have a scenario in which I get a list of unknown type that could be either int\long\short.** If you don't know the type then you'll have to store the type in `List<Object>` only. in that case your answer won't work. Clear?

Answer (score 1):

Nicely simple:

```
var doubleList = listOfObjects.Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(i)).ToList();
```

Micro-optimising because you say "most efficient" is important:

```
int count = listOfObjects.Count;
var doubleList = new List<double>(listOfObjects.Count);
for(int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
  doubleList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(listOfObjects[i]));
```

However, "most efficient" depends on just what you need it to be most efficient at. You get different efficiencies with:

```
public class DoubleList : IList<double>
{
  private readonly List<object> _source; // Change to IList<object> if that's a possibility
  public DoubleList(List<object> source)
  {
    _source = _source;
  }
  // Hide half-supported implementation from main interface
  double IList<double>.this[int index]
  {
    get { return Convert.ToDouble(_source[index]); }
    set { throw new NotSupportedException("Read-only collection"); }
  }
  public double this[int index]
  {
    get { return Convert.ToDouble(_source[index]); }
  }
  public int Count
  {
    get { return _source.Count; }
  }
  bool ICollection<double>.IsReadOnly
  {
    get { return true; }
  }
  /* Lots of boring and obvious implementations skipped */
  public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<double>
  {
    // note, normally we'd just use yield return in the
    // GetEnumerator(), and we certainly wouldn't use
    // a struct here (there are issues), but this
    // optimisation is in the spirit of "most efficient"
    private List<object>.Enumerator _en; //Mutable struct! Don't make field readonly!
    public double Current
    {
      get { return Convert.ToDouble(_en.Current); }
    }
    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
      get { return Current; }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
      _en.Dispose();
    }
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
      return _en.MoveNext();
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
      _en.Reset();
    }
  }
  public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
  {
    return new Enumerator(_source.GetEnumerator());
  }
  IEnumerator<double> IEnumerable<double>.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
}

var doubleList = new DoubleList(listOfObjects);
```

This moves around what happens when in such a way as to change what costs what. You'll return in constant time, but actually using the list will be more expensive. However, if you're only going to look at a few fields, or perhaps only going to obtain the count and then enumerate through it, then the fact that this doesn't do a full copy can make it much more efficient.